# Speed up calculation

Tags: c, cuda, gpgpu

I have an simulation application that I have written both in C and CUDA. To measure the speedup I have recorded the time in both cases. In CUDA, I have used CUDA events to measure the time and then dividing the time of GPU by CPU (as usually done). The image of the speedup is provided below.

The weird thing about the speedup graph is that the speedup first increases to 55X and then it decreases to 35X and then again increases as the total number of thread increases. I am not sure why this is happening and how I would be able to figure out the reason behind such an output. I am using a GTX 560ti GPU card with 448 cores. The number of threads for each block is 1024 (maximum number) and so 1 block at a time for each SM. Is it happening because of the occupancy issues and how could I definitely figure out the reason behind this kind of speedup graph?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you plotted CPU duration and GPU duration instead of speed up so that you can isolate the spike to CPU or GPU. Since you provide no details on the algorithm, execution, or timing methodology no one is going to be able to provide you useful feedback. I would suggest (1) you trace and profile the application, and (2) you use high precision CPU time to time the GPU code from submission of work to completion of work.

Comment: HI!

Thank you for your cooperation. I had the CPU and GPU timing individually which I have uploaded after editing my original post. Actually I am carrying out a simulation and I have measured the timing for GPU and CPU of just the simulation portion. The simulation is basically of pedestrian agents and they are moving in the environment based on some rules and having a global rule. For the CPU time measurement I have used clock()
begin = clock();
for (i=0; i<iteration; i++)
{
}
end = clock();
time_s = (float)(end - begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

Comment: I measure the GPU time using CUDA events and I converted it to seconds. I am not sure what to do or how to find out the reason behind this weird nature of the speedup. It would be extremely helpful if you could guide me how to get the high precision CPU time and also what should look I look in the profiling of the code. I have run my application in a batch mode where the number of agents increases in each time and also the number of threads also increases. I am basically clueless that how could I find the reason behind this sort of graph. Thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The peaks in the speedups seems to be related with the execution times in the CPU. Analyzing the GPU time, it seems to increases lineraly with the number of agents. However, the CPU time, which also increases lineraly in general terms, has a drop time in the range `[0.6,1.6]` aprox, and some peaks in the range `[2.6,3.1]` aprox.

Taking into account the above, your maximum speedup of 55x decreases in the range [0.6,1.1] aprox. because your CPU time also decreases. Therefore, to calculate the speedup as `CPU time / GPU time` is normal that the result is smaller. The same applies to the second, in the range `[2.6,3.1]`.

How could I figure out the reason behind this kind of speedup graph? I guess the the CPU was interrupted by some external event (I/O, other program running in the CPU, the OS...).

To calculate more accurately speedups, **repeat the experiment 10 times as individual executions**, i.e. do not make a loop inside your main function to execute it 10 times. With 10, 20, 30 or even more individual executions you can **calculate the mean time, and also the variance**. Then, study execution times: one or two peaks may be considered as  particular cases (ignore them). If you see a trend, then a deeper study should be done.

Comment: Hi!

Thank you for your suggestion. I was also thinking in the same way but I wasn't sure and so I decided to post it in here. Currently I am accepting your solution as an answer and I would do as you suggested. But if that doesn't solve the anomaly then I would let you know and then we could discuss on this again. Thanks for your support.